# Trino server running on Amazon EMR cluster but cannot access the web UI to view the queries execution and other stats that the web UI provides

Tags: bigdata, amazon-emr, presto, trino

I've verified my Trino server is properly working by looking at the server.log and observing there are no errors and the message "SERVER STARTED" appears. I've connected to my Trino server using JDBC connection in SQL workbench and can successfully run queries in there with data being returned. However, whenever I try to access the web UI to visibly SEE the query execution I get an error message saying "site can't be reached" "ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE". I've tested this on Trino 360 and Trino 388 and same issue persists. I've tried accessing web UI via DNS and IP address and both return the same result. Also, the same results are displayed whether i have "web-ui.enabled=true" in my config.properties or if I omit that property entirely. Has anyone experienced issues accessing Trino Web UI before? Any insight is greatly appreciated.

I am expecting web UI to come up for Trino server

Comment: Did you try Firefox?